# Suddenly unable to save files to sharepoint

Tags: document-library, error

Suddenly the other day whenever users (from multiple machines) start saving files to sharepoint 2010 from Office 2010, it tells them:

Upload Failed This file was not uploaded because the specified path was not found on the server.

This is to the same paths that were working until now. Where would I even start looking to see the cause of this error?

Comment: Out of left field - if you have quotas and locks configured for the site, check the site is not locked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all try to look at ULS logs. You can use [ULS Viewer](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/ULSViewer) for that. Possibly you could see a more detailed description of the issue in these logs. If you have never used ULS Viewer before, you could do the following steps to start troubleshooting:

1. Open ULS Viewer and open ULS logs using its menu (possibly you should press the Play button to start logs showing).
2. Press Ctrl-X to clear old logs.
3. Try to upload a file to repeat the error.
4. Press the pause button in ULS Viewer (to stop showing new logs).
5. Take a look at the collected logs.